# replicating layered blend choice of animations

Tags: unreal-engine4, unreal-blueprint

I'm passing the variables of the TPCHAR to the TPANIMBP but even calling the server the action is not replicating. Where can this error be?

[image: thirdpersoncblueprint]
[image: event graph]
[image: animgraph]

[image: in game no replication]

Answer (score 0):

The Animation is not playing on Remote Clients because your gating it in the Animation Blueprint with a Boolean variable that your only modifying on the calling Client.

[image]

Instead you should be sending an RPC to the Server for when you initiate an Action (Press Left Mouse button?) and when that Action completes (Release Left Mouse button?) so that the Server can appropriately update its State and the State of all Clients, either via Property Replication or as you have done so, a Client (or multicast) RPC to initiate the appropriate code.